# Increase "Explorer" fontsize in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want increase fontsize only in "Explorer" tab, it's possible?

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p8tD.png

Without zoom VSCode Window, only increase fontsize, like editor fontsize in settings.json:

`"editor.fontSize": 14, "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,`

I tried:
CustomizeUI (not work anymore)
Monkey Patch(not work anymore)
Ctrl + Shift + =
Searchs and searchs and searchs

Comment: Unfortunately no... It's zoom the entire window and i don't want this... I really want increase only font size in the "Explorer" tab...